# How to copy individual subitem from ListView?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, copy

I have no idea how to do this.

What I am trying to do is to allow user to copy certain field by using ether right click mouse or keyboard shortcut.

I need this because I am storing some fields as a code which cannot be retyped easily.

ListView allow to select only individual row at the time, and I want to select only one field of the whole table layout.

How do I do this?

PS. Or, how do I allow user to modify the content of each field. At least when they can modify the field they can copy/paste the content (changes will not be saved to my database file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow the user to edit the item, you can set LabelEdit on the ListView to true. Here is the description from MSDN:

"When the LabelEdit property is set to true, the user is able to modify the text of an item by clicking the item text to select it and then clicking the item text again to put the label text into edit mode. The user can then modify or replace the item's text label."

Note that this does not apply to the subitems.

Copying the data out could be slightly more involved depending on the user interface that you desire (i.e. button or context menu). The easy solution would be to add a button to the form that, when pressed, would copy the content of the selected item (or any of its subitems) to the clipboard.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But then I need different button for each subitem, isn't that right? Now, I am coming up with a plan that when item is selected, I will just display the content in a textbox so user can copy it. Would that be a good idea?

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Yes, that is definitely a valid approach.

Answer (score 4):

There is some "Clipboard" class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx

You could simply make a button or something, and set the selected item text in the clipboard.